# Link published packages with git

Tags: git, npm, artifactory

I'm trying to deploy npm in my project.

We use npm and artifactory with a release repository and a snapshot repository. We're working on the snapshot and the release will contain only a few versions. We also use git to save all the sources.

My problem is that the snapshot keep versions only 20 days and some versions will become not be available. Is there a way of linking my versions with git to ensure that all version will always be available ?